# Ignite Persistent Store Loading mechanism

Tags: persistent-storage, ignite

I need the cachestore to be loaded at startup according to its configuration without any additional codes like :

```
CacheStore.load()
```

But in https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store , I could not come accross with an expression that it loads itself at startup automaticly.

am I missing something here or is there really no way to do this at boot time without conding?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I see the following way that should work in your case:

- implement `org.apache.ignite.lifecycle.LifecycleBean` interface and process `org.apache.ignite.lifecycle.LifecycleEventType#AFTER_NODE_START` event in the implementation;
- when the event fires call `cache("cache_name").localLoadCache()` in bean's implementation. Entries for which a started node is either primary or backup will be stored on that node.
- register your `LifecycleBean` implementation with `IgniteConfiguration.setLifecycleBeans(lifeCycleBean)` or the same way in Spring XML.

As a result when a node is started with such configuration the pre-loading will be started automatically because of registered `LifecycleBean`.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/misc/lifecycle/LifecycleExample.java) you can find an example on how to work with `LifecycleBean` in Ignite.